# Direct image of a sheaf with nowhere vanishing sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Suppose that $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism of schemes over the complex numbers and $E$ is a vector bundle on $X$ such that all the sections of $E$ are nowhere vanishing sections. Furthermore, assume that $f_*E$ is a vector bundle on $Y$.

> **Question:**  Is $f_*E$ trivial?

Comment: No. This is already false with $E=\mathscr{O}_X$: take for $f$ a double covering branched along a divisor $D\subset Y$. Then $f_*\mathscr{O}_X=\mathscr{O}_Y\oplus L$, where $L$ is a (nontrivial) line bundle with $L^2=\mathscr{O}_Y(-D)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give a short answer generalizing abx's comment.

If we have a (branched or unbranched) cover of degree $n \geq 1$, say $f \colon X \to Y$, with $X$ connected, then $$f_* \mathcal{O}_X= \mathcal{O}_Y \oplus \mathcal{E},$$ where $\mathcal{E}$ is a (possibly decomposable) vector bundle on $Y$ of rank $n-1$ with $h^0(Y, \, \mathcal{E})=0$. In particular, in this situation $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ is *never trivial*.

In fact, the splitting comes from the trace map applied to the short exact sequence $$0 \to \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_* \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{E} \to 0.$$ Moreover, a finite cover is an affine map, hence $$h^0(Y, \, f_* \mathcal{O}_X)=h^0(X, \, \mathcal{O}_X)=1$$
and so $h^0(Y, \, \mathcal{E})=0$.

Comment: Why does 0 -> O_Y -> f_* O_X -> E -> 0 split?

Comment: In characteristic zero you can use the trace map to provide a splitting of the sequence